# removing all elements with Key Id

Tags: javascript

I click on a button and I pass the id into a function.
Then I want to remove all the ids after that id.

```
folderCollection={
0:{id: 194, name: "Test Update"} 
1:{id: 206, name: "Testssss"}
2:{id: 197, name: "Test11111"}
3:{id: 199, name: "Test11111"}}
```

So for example Id = 206.
the array should only have the two keys now.

```
0:{id: 194, name: "Test Update"} 
1:{id: 206, name: "Testssss"}
```

So I tried using the indexOf to get the indexOf the id and I was going to use splice to remove the other arrays.

```
let Index = folderCollection.indexOf(folderId)
```

But the Index comes back as minus one.
Can anyone help solve this issue?

Comment: Is `folderCollection` an object or array?

Comment: you need to share the dom

Comment: folderCollection is an object.

Comment: `indexOf` only works on arrays not objects

Comment: What you show and what you say contradict each other. Please do `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(folderCollection));` and tell us what it logs.

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that your collection is an `object` and **NOT** and `array` then you can't run `indexOf` on it.

You can achieve your goal in several ways, the most readable in my opinion is this:

```js
const folderCollection = {
  0: {
    id: 194,
    name: "Test Update"
  },
  1: {
    id: 206,
    name: "Testssss"
  },
  2: {
    id: 197,
    name: "Test11111"
  },
  3: {
    id: 197,
    name: "Test11111"
  }
}

const splitBy = 206;
const asArray =
  Object.keys(folderCollection)
  .map(i => folderCollection[i]);

const indexOf = asArray.findIndex(o => o.id === splitBy) + 1;

const sliced = asArray.slice(0, indexOf);

const asObj = {...sliced};

console.log("asObj = ", asObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `filter` like the following:

```js
var folderCollection = [
  {
    id: 194,
    name: "Test Update"
  },
  {
    id: 206,
    name: "Testssss"
  },
  {
    id: 197,
    name: "Test11111"
  },
  {
    id: 197,
    name: "Test11111"
  }
];

function removeByID(id) {
  var result = folderCollection.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.id < id;
  });
  console.log(result);
}

removeByID(197)
```

Comment: folderCollection is an object in his question

Comment: OP wants to remove entries that come _after_ one with a specific ID, not all entries with IDs lower a given number.

Comment: @JosephWebber Edited

Comment: Yes that will not work because the numbers can be in a random order

Comment: @GreatKhan2016 You can pass your number to `removeByID` method to remove items

Comment: That's still not what he wants. If he hands in 206 he wants to remove everything that comes after 206 (197, 197), not everything lower than 206 (194, 197, 197).

Comment: @JosephWebber Edited

Comment: `.filter` is not the correct solution for his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is malformed.

Try this:

```js
let folderCollection=[
{id: 194, name: "Test Update"}, 
{id: 206, name: "Testssss"},
{id: 197, name: "Test11111"},
{id: 197, name: "Test11111"}]
var index = folderCollection.findIndex(x=>x.id==206);
if(index>-1)
    folderCollection.splice(index+1, folderCollection.length-index);
console.log(folderCollection);
```

Comment: his array is not malformed. It is a object. That much is clear.

Comment: If folderCollection is an object, then it is not a valid syntax. OP mentioned this as an array multiple times on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most concise code, but quite readable in my opinion
https://jsfiddle.net/ak724hty/12/

```
let folderCollection={
    0:{id: 194, name: "Test Update"} ,
    1:{id: 206, name: "Testssss"},
    2:{id: 197, name: "Test11111"},
    3:{id: 197, name: "Test11111"}
}

const filterCollectionById = function(collection, id) {
  let keyArray = Object.keys(collection);
  let filteredCollection = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {

    filteredCollection[i] = collection[i];

    if(collection[i].id === id) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return filteredCollection;

}

console.log(filterCollectionById(folderCollection, 206));
```

By default, you can't iterate through on object, that's why you have to first make an array out of it's keys.

Then you can iterate through, and once you have found the wanted objects it stops. If you don't have an object where that ID is present, you just simply return the full object. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const folderCollection = {
  0: {
    id: 194,
    name: "Test Update"
  },
  1: {
    id: 206,
    name: "Testssss"
  },
  2: {
    id: 197,
    name: "Test11111"
  },
  3: {
    id: 197,
    name: "Test11111"
  }
}

function removingElements(collection, id) {
  const array = Object.values(collection);
  const index = array.findIndex(elm => elm.id === id);
  return array.reduce((newCollection, elm, currentIndex) => {
    if (index === -1 || currentIndex <= index) {
      newCollection[currentIndex] = elm;
    }
    return newCollection;
  }, {});
}

const result =  removingElements(folderCollection, 206);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a example more:

```js
var folderCollection={
0:{id: 194, name: "Test Update"}, 
1:{id: 206, name: "Testssss"},
2:{id: 197, name: "Test11111"},
3:{id: 197, name: "Test11111"}};
function deleteAfterKey(value){
    var temp = Object.keys(folderCollection);
    var test = temp.filter(function(row) {
        return folderCollection[row].id===value;
    });
    var idObject = test[0]; //console.log(idObject);
    if(idObject){
        for(var i=temp.length-1; i>idObject;i--){
            //console.log(i);
            delete folderCollection[i];
            //console.log(folderCollection);
        }
    }
}
deleteAfterKey(206);
console.log(folderCollection);
```